# How to add multiple characters to one index in a Char Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

Im currently trying to create a function where my input is a string such as "AABBCCDDEE" and the function outputs a String array "AA""BB""CC" and so on.

```
    public static char[] stringSplitter(final String input) {

            String[] strarray = new String[input.length()];
            if (input == null) {
                return null;
            }
            char[] chrarray = input.toCharArray();
            char[] outputarray = new char[input.length()];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < chrarray.length; i++) {
                char chr = chrarray[i];
                System.out.print(chr);
                outputarray[j] = chrarray[i]; //here i need to find a way to add the characters to the index at j if the preceding characters are equal
                if (i + 1 < input.length() && chrarray[i + 1] != chr) {
                    j++;
                    outputarray[j] = chrarray[i + 1];
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to find "runs?"  Sequences of contiguous characters that are the same?

Comment: Yes, and each run should be in a seperate index

Comment: You realize you can't store *\*multiple\** characters at a single index, right?  You'll need to use a two dimensional char array, a string, or something else.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for the clarification. this means that i would only be able to use a string array

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed-length, so you can't do this with an array unless you allocate one with sufficient extra room up-front (which would require a pass through the string to find out how much extra room you needed).

Instead, consider using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for the output, which you can convert into a `char` array when you're done.

Comment: How do you convert from StringBuilder to chararray. Is there a .toCharArray method?

Comment: @airbmx - See the documentation linked above. There isn't a `toCharArray`, no, but there is a [`getChars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#getChars(int,int,char%5B%5D,int)) that gets you there. (Or convert to `String` first and use `String`'s `toCharArray`.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to split the characters in a string so that similar-consecutive characters stay together. If that's the case, here is how I would do it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> splitString(String str) {
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    String combo = "";

    //iterates through all the characters in the input
    for(char c: str.toCharArray()) {
        //check if the current char is equal to the last added char
        if(combo.length() > 0 && c != combo.charAt(combo.length() - 1)) {
            output.add(combo);    
            combo = "";
        }

        combo += c;
    }

    output.add(combo); //adds the last character  
    return output;
}
```

Note that instead of using an array (has a fixed size) to store the output, I used an `ArrayList`, which has a variable size. Also, note that it's a list of strings (stores strings), not characters. The reason for this is that if it was a list of characters I wouldn't be able to store more than one character in the same index.

In each iteration of the loop, I check for equality between the current character and it's consecutive. The variable `combo` is used to temporarily store the characters (in a string) before they go to `output`.

Now, to print the results in a clear way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String input = "EEEE  BCD DdA";
    ArrayList<String> output = splitString(input);

    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("\"" + output.get(i) + "\"");

        if(i != output.size()-1) 
            System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

The output when running the above code will be:

`["EEEE", "  ", "B", "C", "D", " ", "D", "d", "A"]`

Comment: thank you, unfortunately im not well versed in array lists, so ill have to take a dive into the java documentation on what it is before I fully understand your code. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! An `ArrayList` is, briefly, an array with a variable size. It's use isn't that much different than of a normal array. I've also added a few more explanations of my code in the answer, check it and see if it helps you better understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList of type String to store the consecutive letter Strings after splitting them. This code should work for you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringSplitter{
        static ArrayList<String> splitString(String str)
        {
            ArrayList<String> result_list= new ArrayList<String>();
            int last_index;
            if(str == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                while(str.length() != 0)
                {
                last_index = str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(0));
                result_list.add(str.substring(0, last_index+1));
                str = str.substring(last_index+1);
                }
            }
            return result_list;
            }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ArrayList<String> result = splitString("AABBCCDDEEE");
            System.out.println(result);

        }
     }
```

I have used an ArrayList because it does not require you to fix a size while declaration.